# How to insert PRINTDATE field code in a sentence using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to get the following sentence inside my doc: "This document was last printed on 01/01/2019 2:10 AM". The date and time must be dynamic. Right now I only have this part:

```
Element.Range.Text = "This document was last printed on "
```

It works, but it's missing the date part. What should I do to get the `PRINTDATE` field concatenated into this sentence?

I tried

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, Type:=wdFieldPrintDate, Text:="\@""DD MMM YYYY""", preserveformatting:=True
```

and it works, but it's overwriting all the footer, how can I append it to the text to make it similar to my example?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`Fields.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.fields.add) and `wdFieldPrintDate` from the [WdFieldType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdfieldtype).

Comment: Hum... I tried `Selection.Fields.Add Range:=.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, Type:=wdFieldPrintDate, Text:="\@""DD MMM YYYY""", preserveformatting:=True` and it works, but it's overwriting all the footer, how can I append it to the text to make it similar to my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the Footer associated with a Selection:

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Set rng = Selection.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
```

To then *append* to that Range:

```
rng.InsertAfter " This document was last printed on " 'don't forget a space at the beginning
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'so the inserted field comes AFTER
rng.Fields.Add Range:=rng,  Type:=wdFieldPrintDate, _
    Text:="\@""DD MMM YYYY""", preserveformatting:=False
```

Note: I highly recommend using `PreserveFormatting:=False` as the field is more likely to pick up the formatting of the surrounding text if other formatting is applied. Setting this to `True` will retain the originally applied formatting for the *number of characters originally in the field*. If the field is updated and the number of characters changes, some of the characters may be formatted differently from the rest.

Indeed, I prefer using the method more as follows, with all the field content in the `Text` parameter, including the `CharFormat` switch. `CharFormat` will *force* the entire field to use the character formatting applied to the first character in the field code - much more reliable:

```
rng.Fields.Add Range:=rng,  Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    Text:="PrintDate \@""DD MMM YYYY"" \* CharFormat", preserveformatting:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will change all footers in a document to show "The document was last printed on {dd.mm.yyyy}. It might be modified not to replace all of the footer.

```
Sub ModifyFooter()
    ' 03 Jan 2019

    Dim Doc As Document
    Dim Txt As String
    Dim Foot As HeaderFooter
    Dim Para As Paragraph
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As WdHeaderFooterIndex

    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    For i = wdHeaderFooterPrimary To wdHeaderFooterFirstPage
        Set Foot = Doc.Sections(1).Footers(i)
        Txt = "This document was last printed on "
        Set Para = Foot.Range.Paragraphs(1)
        Set Rng = Para.Range
        With Rng
            .Text = Txt
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End With
        Txt = "\@ ""dd.MM.yyyy"""
        Doc.Fields.Add Rng, wdFieldPrintDate, Text:=Txt, PreserveFormatting:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
With ActiveDocument
  .Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Sections.First.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Characters.Last, _
    Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PRINTDATE \@""'This document was last printed on 'DD MMM YYYY""", PreserveFormatting:=False
End With
```